# Screen blinking on moving cursor from one monitor to another

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup at work and when moving the cursor from one monitor to the other the screen blinks and sometimes gets completely black.

I've recorded a [video](https://vid.me/vgEE) to better show the problem:

https://vid.me/vgEE

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 (clean install). This wasn't happening in 15.10.

Comment: Seems like this bug happened again in Ubuntu 16.10 (4.8.0-26 kernel).

Comment: Got clean Ubuntu 16.04 (4.10.0-32-generic), happens as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello i had the same problem but solved it by installing latest upstream kernel from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D). At [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) you can find installing instruction. Right now i use 4.6.0rc4 and it works well.

Comment: I have the same issue. I was wondering if you just grabbed the latest kernel or if you picked based on the ubuntu version notation. ie did you pick a xenial version or just the latest?

Comment: just latest version

Answer (score 0):

[This is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1553503). 
The issue is fixed in 4.4.0.38 kernel.