# black screen for one second since upgrading to 16.10

Tags: unity, ubuntu-gnome, 16.10

Since upgrading recently to Ubuntu 16.10, every now and then the screen goes black for about a second before the image returns again. Each time this happens, /var/log/syslog shows the messages below (some maybe in a slightly different order, but otherwise the same).

Has anyone also encountered this phenomenon?

```
Oct 27 11:26:22 myhost systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of root.
Oct 27 11:26:22 myhost systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 0...
Oct 27 11:26:22 myhost systemd[1]: Started Session 25 of user root.
Oct 27 11:26:22 myhost systemd[32077]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 27 11:26:22 myhost systemd[32077]: Reached target Paths.
Oct 27 11:26:22 myhost systemd[32077]: Reached target Timers.
Oct 27 11:26:22 myhost systemd[32077]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 27 11:26:22 myhost systemd[32077]: Reached target Sockets.
Oct 27 11:26:22 myhost systemd[32077]: Reached target Basic System.
Oct 27 11:26:22 myhost systemd[32077]: Starting Run Click user-level hooks...
Oct 27 11:26:22 myhost systemd[32077]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost content-hub-pee[32117]: Error parsing manifest for package 'com.ubuntu.gallery': com.ubuntu.gallery does not exist in any database for user root
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[774]: daemon.go:174: DEBUG: uid=0;@ GET /v2/snaps/com.ubuntu.gallery 37.934µs 404
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost content-hub-pee[32117]: Unable to get snap information for 'com.ubuntu.gallery': Status code is: 404
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost dbus-daemon[32098]: Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf'
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost content-hub-pee[32117]: Error parsing manifest for package 'com.ubuntu.gallery': com.ubuntu.gallery does not exist in any database for user root
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[774]: daemon.go:174: DEBUG: uid=0;@ GET /v2/snaps/com.ubuntu.gallery 42.936µs 404
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost content-hub-pee[32117]: Unable to get snap information for 'com.ubuntu.gallery': Status code is: 404
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost dbus-daemon[32098]: Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost dbus-daemon[32098]: Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' unit='gvfs-daemon.service'
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost systemd[32077]: Starting Virtual filesystem service...
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost dbus-daemon[32098]: Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost systemd[32077]: Started Virtual filesystem service.
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost click[32094]: /usr/lib/ubuntu-push-client/click-hook:15: PyGIWarning: Click was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Click', '0.4') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost click[32094]:   from gi.repository import Click
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost click[32094]: hooks.vala:1216: User-level hook push-helper failed: Hook command '/usr/lib/ubuntu-push-client/click-hook-wrapper' failed: Child process exited with code 1
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost click[32094]: Nothing to install.
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost click[32094]: Nothing to update.
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost click[32094]: Nothing to delete.
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost click[32094]: Some user-level hooks failed: push-helper
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost systemd[32077]: click-user-hooks.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost systemd[32077]: Failed to start Run Click user-level hooks.
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost systemd[32077]: click-user-hooks.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost systemd[32077]: click-user-hooks.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost systemd[32077]: Reached target Default.
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost systemd[32077]: Startup finished in 863ms.
Oct 27 11:26:23 myhost systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 0.
```

Information on my system:

```
Kernel          : Linux 4.8.0-22-generic (x86_64)
Compiled        : #24-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 8 09:15:00 UTC 2016
C Library       : GNU C Library version (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.24-3ubuntu1) 2.24 (unstable)
Default C Compiler: GNU C Compiler version 6.2.0 20161005 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 
Distribution        : Ubuntu 16.10
Desktop Environment : Unity (ubuntu)
Processor       : 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100 CPU @ 3.70GHz

Display:
Iiyama North America 24"
Resolution      : 1920x1200 pixels
OpenGL Renderer : Unknown
X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation

Video card: Intel HD Graphics 530 (rev06), Kernel module i915
```

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/760836/screen-blinking-on-moving-cursor-from-one-monitor-to-another This is a bug. The issue is fixed in 4.4.0.38 kernel.

Comment: @JelledenButter Well, then the bug has got again unfixed: I'm running 4.8.0-22 on Ubuntu 16.10, well beyond 4.4.