# Ubuntu 16.10 dual display restart

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I've updated my Ubuntu 16.04 to version 16.10. I have 2 displays that connected to workstation. One of them (right one) is connected via HDMI, and second (left) is connected via D-SUB.

On 16.04 I had no issues with displays, but after update I found that when I move cursor from left display to right display, left one restarts just in moment when cursor reached and stepped through border between displays.

How can I fix this? I think that problem is in some drivers

Comment: What's the output to `lshw -class video`???

Comment: @Fabby
    *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:123 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to [Screen blinking on moving cursor from one monitor to another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760836/screen-blinking-on-moving-cursor-from-one-monitor-to-another) and was fixed by updating kernel to upstream